# Running python scripts does not create Airflow DAG?

Tags: python, airflow, directed-acyclic-graphs

I ssh'd into a linux server to run Airflow. I have made the scheduler(`airflow scheduler -D`) and database initialized (`airflow db init`). However, even when trying to create the simplest of DAGs using python (I also tried using Airflow's predefined example py scripts), Airflow does not list the DAG when running the `airflow dags list` command.

I'm sure the syntax of my py code is correct because the DAG showed up on a windows instance but my setup for airflow within Linux is somehow not correct? Also used `python3 script.py` to execute.

Comment: Which type of "deployment" do you have? Are you sure you have all the instances needed up and running? Can you access Airflow UI?

Answer (score 1):

Basically the dags folder's permission's weren't allowing anything to be written into it. I just sudo'd every command or chmod the folder. Also to ensure Airflow was correctly run, I suggest using a YAML file with docker compose to streamline Airflow setup.